# Disable general public key authentication but allow SSH via CA

Tags: ssh, security, certificate-authority

I would like to disable general pubKey authentication on my server and only allow auth via signed SSH CA (cert authority).

To enable SSH via CA you add this line:

`TrustedUserCAKeys /etc/ssh/trusted-user-ca-keys.pem`

However, I want to explicitly disable standard pubKey auth (and password for that matter).

So when I do:

`PubkeyAuthentication no`

CA stops working.

How can I achieve what Im trying to do here. Is the only option to empty the authorizedKeys file?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you can set `AuthorizedKeysFile` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to `/dev/null` or something?  Worth a try